# How to delete certain nodes from a regression tree built by `ctree()` from `party` package

Tags: r, decision-tree, party

I've built a regression tree using `ctree()` from package `party`. 
The results of my model have many nodes which contain equal probability of dependent variables (E.g. : class A = 0.33, class B = 0.33, Class C = 0.33). I want to take out these nodes from the model. The package `tree` has the `snip.tree()` command where we can specify the node numbers to be deleted from the model.This command does not recognize regression trees built with `ctree()`. Please let me know if there is a way to delete certain nodes from a regression tree built using `ctree()`

I have used the model:

```
rv.mod1 <- ctree(ldclas ~ L2 + L3 + L4 + L5 + L6 + ele + ndvi + nd_var + nd_ps, data = rv, controls = ctree_control(minsplit = 0, minbucket = 0))
pr.rv.mod1 <- snip.tree(rv.mod1, nodes = nn2.rv.mod1$nodes)
```

nn2.rv.mod1$nodes is a vector with nodes to be deleted from the rv.mod1 model.But I get an error:

```
Error in snip.tree(rv.mod1, nodes = nn2.rv.mod1$nodes) : 
  not legitimate tree
```

Comment: Could you show us what you have tryed so for? Also: please read the help page on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is direct way to do this, but I will propose a "hack" using the `weights` argument in `ctree`.

Let's start with a reproducible example

```
library(party)
irisct <- ctree(Species ~ .,data = iris)
plot(irisct)
```

[image]

Now, suppose you want to get rid of node number 5. You can do the following

```
NewWeigths <- rep(1, dim(iris)[1]) # Setting a weights vector which will be passed into the `weights` attribute in `ctree`
Node <- 5 # Selecting node #5
n <- nodes(irisct, Node)[[1]] # Retrieving the weights of that node
NewWeigths[which(as.logical(n$weights))] <- 0 # Setting these weigths to zero, so `ctree` will disregard them
irisct2 <- ctree(Species ~ .,data = iris, weights = NewWeigths) # creating the new tree with new weights
plot(irisct2)
```

[image]

Note how nodes 2, 6 and 7 (now they are named 2, 4 and 5 because we have less splits) remained exactly with the same distribution and splitting conditions.

I didn't test it for all nodes, but it seem to work fairly well